# ssh-keygen raise password too short error when called with subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, ssh-keygen

I would like to know if I need to do something differently when I call `ssh-keygen`in a script by using`subprocess`or not .
I'm running in a Linux Environment.
Here is my code:

```
    cfg_r = configparser.ConfigParser()
    cfg_r.read('ssh_config.cfg')
    p_mail=cfg_r.get('Company', 'mail')
    bashCo m mand="ssh-keygen -t rsa -f /home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa  - C \"{}\" -q -N \"\"".format(p_mail)
    print(bashCommand.split())
    proc = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand.split(),
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=open('logfile_Get_conf.log', 'a'),
            preexec_fn=os.setpgrp
            )
    outpu.stdout.read().decode('utf-8')
```

I use `configparser` to read email other than this, nothing special.

`bashCommand` is as it should be:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f /home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa -C "mail@gmail.com" -q -N ""
```

`bashCommand.split()` is as it should be too:

```
['ssh-keygen', '-t', 'rsa', '-f', '/home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa', '-C', '"mail@gmail.com"', '-q', '-N', '""']
```

The thing that's very weird is when I run this `bashCommand` in the shell, no problems occur:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f /home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa -C "mail@gmail.com" -q -N ""
```

But in my log file I still have this error:

```
Saving key "/home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa" failed: passphrase is too short (minimum five characters)
```

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you are running in a Unix-like environment with a shell like `bash` or similar (as the variable `bashCommand` implies). Things work very differently in Windows.

When you run the command you show in the shell, the arguments passed to `ssh-keygen` as `argv` are (in Python syntax):

```
['ssh-keygen', '-t', 'rsa', '-f', '/home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa', '-C', 'mail@gmail.com', '-q', '-N', '']
```

The shell expands out the strings, and strips off any quotes. When you split your command, the arguments are passed as-is, since you did not specify `shell=True` to `Popen`. That means that `ssh-keygen`'s `argv` will be

```
['ssh-keygen', '-t', 'rsa', '-f', '/home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa', '-C', '"mail@gmail.com"', '-q', '-N', '""']
```

Hopefully you can see the difference. The argument to `-N` is no longer empty. It is a two-character string `""`, which is clearly less than five characters.

You do not need the string `bashCommand`. It is much more convenient to use lists, and pass things to `Popen` directly that way:

```
bashCommand = ['ssh-keygen', '-t', 'rsa', '-f', '/home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa', '-C', p_mail, '-q', '-N', '']
proc = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand, ...)
```

Notice that this way, you don't need to do any string interpolation, fancy splitting, quoting, escaping, or other modifications to the command line.

I had mentioned that things work very differently on Windows. That's because on Windows, `shell=True` is *always* set, and there is nothing you can do about it. Windows does not pass `argv` to a program like Unix does. Instead, programs are responsible for parsing their own command line strings, so having the quotes is mandatory. Using `shell=True` is generally frowned upon, so I don't recommend using it as a solution for the Unix-like case (but it would work).

As mentioned in the comments, there are other issues with robustness, maintainability, and aesthetics in your code. However, none of them should prevent it from functioning correctly.

Comment: Also, don't use bare `Popen()` if `subprocess.check_output()` or `subprocess.run()` can do what you want.

Comment: @tripleee. And don't use camelCase for variable names, but that's not as important as understanding how the command line works.

Comment: Okayyy, I get it ! And you explained it it can't be more perfect. Thank-you very much !! Okay I take note of it.